# Section Tab Missing on Document Tool Bar

Tags: pages

I want to change the starting page number in a Pages document but I don't (seem to) have the Section tab on the Document side tool bar.  How do I get it bacK?

Comment: The Section tab along with Document and Bookmarks tabs should appear on the right when you click on the Document icon at the top right in the Pages toolbar. What happens when you click on the Document icon in the Pages toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

1. It was changed in Pages 10.
   Mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251276404), but I found it to be tricky to get to, especially without much experience with this app. For one thing, you have to make sure thumbnails are visible with View -> Page Thumbnails.
2. Here you can see the thumbnails on the left. On the right hand side you can only see Format and Document. [image]
3. Finally after clicking on the thumbnail, Section finally shows up. IT WILL DISAPPEAR when you click in the document body.
   [image: Section shows up dynamically]